# angularjs get max value on certain column

Tags: angularjs

iam new on angularjs and reading the doc about orderBy
, wanting to know how to get the max value on certain column,

like the oldest person is Adam - 35

```
Name (^)    Phone Number    Age
Adam         555-5678       35
Julie        555-8765       29
Mike         555-4321       21
Mary         555-9876       19
John         555-1212       10
```

the example [on plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/siOArRh6XK7hKRGoOkEP?p=preview)

does anyone know how to do it?

thank you

Comment: `orderBy` is to sort the entries of a collection. It has got nothing to do with finding the max and min values. You either create a custom filter that will give you the max value or simply use regular old javascript to find it yourself.

Comment: like get the max data from the controller side? i'll try it

Comment: ordeyBy doesn't manipulate the original model ,its just for view purpose i think you need to sort your object array in controller and then pick the max

Comment: @user716409 yes correct. Get it from the controller by iterating over the collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this is what you are looking for:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.friends = [
    {name:'John', phone:'555-1212', age:10},
    {name:'Mary', phone:'555-9876', age:19},
    {name:'Mike', phone:'555-4321', age:21},
    {name:'Adam', phone:'555-5678', age:35},
    {name:'Julie', phone:'555-8765', age:29}
  ];
  $scope.change = function(o) {
    var arr = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.friends, function(item) {
      arr.push(item[o]);
    });
    $scope.result = arr.sort()[0];
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <select ng-model="val" ng-change="change(val)">
    <option>name</option>
    <option>phone</option>
    <option>age</option>
  </select>
  <p>sorted first value: {{result}}</p>
</div>
```